# Creating an excel workbook with selected rows

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets. one of the sheets has several rows with items. I also have a second sheet also with items. Each of the items in sheet one has corresponding item in sheet 2. What I would like to do is when someone selects on a yes for the items on sheet one then the rows from sheet 2 of the same item are copied into a new workbook.

For example Sheet 1 would have

```
Code1 Apple yes/no
Code2 Banana yes/no
Code3 Mango yes/no
```

Where yes/no is a data validation input under column C

Sheet 2 would have

```
Code1 20032
Code2 30045
Code3 50098
```

So once a user makes a selection of yes/no on sheet 1 and clicks a button an excel workbook should be genrated with the rows from sheet 2 without those selected as No.

I tried to record a Macro using filters but since my sheet 2 has merged cells, the copying did not work well

Comment: Merged cells and VBA don't go together very well. I'd consider remodeling your data.